# Hibernate Creating a Map Collection Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create a Hibernate  XML mapping for the following POJO Classes:

```
public class Topics {

      private int topicId;

      private Map<Integer,News> news;

      //setters and getters
}

public class News {

     private int newsId;

     private Map<Integer,Topics> newstopics;

     //setters and getters
}
```

My Tables are these:

```
CREATE TABLE topics (
   topicid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (topicid)
) 
CREATE TABLE news (
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 
CREATE TABLE newstopics (
   topicid int(11) NOT NULL,
   newsid int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (topicid,newsid),
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (topicid) REFERENCES topics (topicid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (newsid) REFERENCES news (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I am trying something like this, but it is not working:

```
<class name="Topics" table="topics">
   <id name="topicId" type="int" column="topicid"><generator class="native"/></id>
   <map name="news" table="newstopics">
        <key column="topicid"/>
        <map-key  column="newsid" type="int"/>
        <many-to-many column="newsId" class="News" />
    </map>
</class>

 <class name="News" table="news">
    <id name="newsId" type="int" column="id"><generator class="native"/></id>
    <map name="newstopics" table="newstopics">
        <key column="newsid" />
        <map-key  column="topicid" type="int"/>
         <many-to-many column="topicId" class="Topics" />
    </map>
</class>
```

Goal is to achieve a bidirectional mapping, meaning that when something changes in one map the contents of newstopics get updated too. I have tried multiple variations for the mapping of the maps but no luck. The most disturbing aspect ist that the hibernate genarated SELECTs and INSERTs from/to the newstopics table are looking for more that its 2 columns. For example INSERT INTO newstopics (topicid,newsid,id) VALUES ? ? ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a `Map` ? Typical would be the use of a one-to-many mapping - e.g. `List` of `Topic`s, where `Topic` contains the primary key of the `Topic`- `id`. The datamodel is confusing as well - The News contains topics - ok, News is the container of topics. But the topics contain news as well?

Comment: I am using a Map to be able to access and update the Objects without having to go through the whole collection. This datamodel is just an example I have also other similar relationships in my application. And it makes sence that a topic should contain news so that you can list the news by topic